# How can I get a limit over $10,000 for my debit card?

Tags: debit-card

I have a Mastercard debit card from my bank and they tell me the maximum limit they can put on the card is $10,000. They said if I want a card that goes higher than this, then I have to use a credit card. I do not use credit cards as a matter of principle (among other reasons), so that is not an option for me.

How can I get a debit card with a higher limit, or is that even possible?

(I know that I can *temporarily* have the limit increased. That is not the question. The question is how to permanently increase the limit.)

Comment: Do you really need a daily limit over $10,000?

Comment: Is this the daily limit? If so, I agree with Brian, why in the world do you need to spend more than $10,000 a day?

Comment: It is quite dangerous to have a high limit on a debit card, as the money is gone when the card is stolen, skimmed, or otherwise abused. You didn't explain your denial for credit cards, but that is the one major difference - _credit cards cover fraud for you_. Unless you are a multi-millionaire, you will get badly hurt for sticking with a debit card one day. - I didn't write an answer, because I think it's not possible. There is no interest in the market, because it is a wild and unnecessary risk, so banks don't offer it. But I don't know exactly for all banks, of course.

Comment: In my thirty years of adulthood I have never charged a credit or debit card with $10,000 in a single day. I have never stayed in a $750 a night hotel, but if I had I would either settle up frequently enough that the bill never went over $10,000, or I would open an account with the hotel so it didn't need to be settled by card. The point is - you are clearly in a very unusual situation, and if you told us more about what about your situation made you need to do this we could help.

Comment: Also what is your objection to credit cards? Would a [charge card](https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/support-cardmember/credit-know-how/what-is-charge.html) work for you instead?

Answer (score 1):

Most people wouldn't ever have the opportunity to need a $10,000 daily limit on there debit cards unless there purchasing Lamborghinis yachts and jet fuel.  But Im not sure that they use a debit card when doing that either, sorry

Answer (score 1):

First, let me congratulate you on having sufficient income to run into this unique problem. As mentioned in the comments, $10,000/day is quite high for a debit card so the limit is not surprising.

That said, you have a few options:

1. Ask the bank if another debit-based product exists with a limit you can accept
2. Look at other banks or credit unions. Some do offer debit cards without any daily limit on use: the Wings Financial Credit Union in the states comes to mind as well as my local bank.
3. Investigate other ways of making large purchases in a short period of time. Checks, credit cards, charge-cards, and a variety of other digital payment methods may be a better option to reduce the risk of having a card with a limit that high.

Answer (score 1):

My bank only offers a limit of € 3000. If you want a higher limit, you will probably have to change banks.